# longtable example+error:Package longtable Error: Column widths have changed in table

Tags: xetex, longtable, landscape

I'm trying to use a longtable in landscape. I obtain a compilation error (I use XeLaTex) and I don't know where is the problem.
The code is:

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{ccccccc}
\caption{My table.}
\label{tab:table} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{D} & \multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{E} & \multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{F}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize\itshape\tablename~\thetable: continue from previous page} \\ 
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{D} & \multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{E} & \multicolumn{1}{c}\textbf{F}\\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape\tablename~\thetable: continue to next page} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape\tablename~\thetable: end} \\
\endlastfoot
% table body
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\midrule
\textbf{1} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
\bottomrule                                 
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

The error is:

```
 Package longtable Error: Column widths have changed in table 2.1 
 See the longtable package documentation for explanation. 
 Type  H <return>  for immediate help. 
 ...                                              

 l.901 \end{longtable}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an error. Compile again until the problem goes away: `longtable` uses previous runs to adjust the column width in order to get them the same size on all pages.

If you load the package **longtable** with the option pausing, the informative message is indeed changed into an error; omit that option, in case you're using it.